# When talking about a batter, what does shutout mean?

Tags: baseball

At about 7′30″ into the video linked below, the announcer says "That's **shotout** to center field."

As far as I know, [shutout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shutouts_in_baseball) refers to the act by which a single pitcher pitches a complete game and does not allow the opposing team to score a run strikes, which is obvious not what the announcer means.

So what does shutout there mean?

The link starts at 7′22″.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word is "Shot out", not "Shut out".  "Shot out" in this context refers to the meaning of "Shot" similar to "shot from a gun" - i.e., a hard blast as opposed to a soft "bloop" hit.